# How to: Hover the image and animating draw a line and description fade out

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, effects

As title, if I want to achieve some effect like giving description to the hovering over an image and a div box with description will be fade out right under the line, how could I achieve this with Javascript or jQuery or CSS3? Thank you for reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have the image and description in a div, set the div height to the image height and overflow:hidden;

Then take the over flow off on :hover

Use CSS transitions for a smooth effect